# Selected option deselecting after onIonChange event

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I'm recently learning to work with Ionic and React and I wanted to make a forms with an IonSelect item where the user chooses a gender option. If the user chooses `female` then I have a function where another IonInput appears otherwise it stays hidden. Like this:

```
<IonItem><IonLabel>Gender</IonLabel>
<Controller as = {
<IonSelect placeholder="Please select...">
        <IonSelectOption value="female" >Female</IonSelectOption>
        <IonSelectOption value="male">Male</IonSelectOption>
</IonSelect> 
}

control={control}
name="gender"
onIonChange={onChange}/></IonItem>  

{showOptions ? 
  <IonItem>
     <IonLabel position="floating">Date:</IonLabel>
     <IonDatetime placeholder="Select date"></IonDatetime>
   </IonItem>: null}
```

And the functions:

```
 const [showOptions, setShowOptions] = React.useState(false);
 const onChange = ((e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLIonSelectElement>) : void => {
 const value = e.currentTarget.value;

    console.log(value);
   
    if (value == "female"){
        setShowOptions(true);
       }
    else if (value == "male"){
        setShowOptions(false);
    }})
```

It's working fine, the hidden item appears when the user selects `female`, but for some reason after the `onChange` event occurs the `IonSelectOption` is deselected, going back to the placeholder text. How do I fix this and keep the original selection after the `onChange` event?

edit

So I used the watch function and now it's working, the only problem is that everytime I choose either the female or male option, my other component wrapped around Controller resets.
This is my code now:

```
<IonItem>
    <IonLabel position="floating">Email:</IonLabel>
        <Controller control= {control} as =          
           {<IonInput type="email"/>}
           name= "email"
           rules= {{required:true}} />
</IonItem> 

<IonItem>
    <IonLabel >Gender:</IonLabel>
        <Controller render={({onChange}) => ( 
        <IonSelect placeholder="Please select..." id="gender" 
         onIonChange={(e) => {
                                console.log(e);
                                onChange(e.detail.value)
                            }}>
        <IonSelectOption value="female" >Female</IonSelectOption>
        <IonSelectOption value="male">Male</IonSelectOption>
        </IonSelect> 
        )}
        control={control}
        name="gender"
        rules={{required: true}} />    
</IonItem>

{watchGender == "female" ? 
    <IonItem>
    <IonDatetime placeholder="Select date"></IonDatetime>
    </IonItem>: null}
```

The functions:

```
const {control, watch, handleSubmit} = useForm();

const watchGender= watch("gender", "");
```

Comment: looks like you are using react-hook form? would be helpful if you include the complete component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See solution here in codesandbox.io
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-ionic-input-components-forked-t9zvg?file=/src/index.js

basically, I am using the `watch` function to determine if the gender changes

```
  const watchShowGender = watch("gender", "");
```

In the template

```
<IonItem>
  <IonLabel>Gender</IonLabel>
  <Controller
    render={({ onChange }) => (
      <IonSelect
        placeholder="Select One"
        onIonChange={(e) => {
          console.log(e);
          onChange(e.detail.value);
        }}
      >
        <IonSelectOption value="FEMALE">Female</IonSelectOption>
        <IonSelectOption value="MALE">Male</IonSelectOption>
      </IonSelect>
    )}
    control={control}
    name="gender"
    rules={{ required: true }}
  />
</IonItem>
```

And

```
{watchShowGender === "FEMALE" ? (
  <IonItem>
    <IonLabel position="floating">Date:</IonLabel>
    <IonDatetime placeholder="Select date"></IonDatetime>
  </IonItem>
) : null}
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. I'll take a look at this watch function.

Comment: The only problem I've find is that this method is resetting my other IonInput wrapped around a Controller component (it's just an email input) and I can't quite figure out why.

Comment: i added and email field and I am not seeing g error

Comment: @deadpool  please modify the codesandbox project with your new field only, I don't want to have to keep recreating the project from your code - and your edits have implement react-hoof form incorrect... please look at the project I created

Comment: Ok, I understand. I should use 'render' parameter instead of 'as' to do what I wanted, makes sense. It's working now